# Blank displays (no boot screen, no "check signal cable")

Tags: hardware-failure

**Background**

I have a desktop computer I built myself about 2 years ago that suddenly stopped sending signals to my displays. I have two identical displays connected to the computer using VGA and DVI and both simply go into standby mode when the computer is on (they still show "check signal cable" if unplugged).

**I have tried**

- Connected another screen of different brand, which acts the same way (standby mode)
- Powered everything off, opened the computer and inspected all the parts, which seem to be functioning.

**Theory 1: Video card broken**

If the computer powers on normally, it should automatically start both an Apache server and SSH server, which it doesnt, so it seems like something breaks during the boot process.

Also, if video card is broken, shouldn´t the motherboard "beep"?

**Theory 2: Screens broken**

Seems unlikely since I have three screens of two different brands which all act the same way.

**Theory 3: Motherboard broken**

If the motherboard breaks, shouldn´t it "beep"?

**Here is the spec:**

RAM: Corsair Dominator DHX+ DDR3 1600MHz 6GB
CPU: Intel Core? i7 Quad Processor i7-920
Motherboard: Asus P6T SE, X58, Socket-1366
Videocard: XFX GeForce 9500GT 550M 1GB PhysX CUDA
PSU: Chieftec Smart Series PSU ATX 550W
OS HDD: OCZ Vertex Series SATAII 2.5" SSD 30GB

Anyway, I appreciate any help or pointers!

Comment: **Therory 4: PSU br0ken** The PSU might not be stable enough due to aging or dust buildup. And a br0ken motherboard may or may not beep.

Comment: I believe in either theory 3 or 4.  If you're not seeing your BIOS screen, then these are the usual suspects.  The easy test is to try a working PSU.  Are the fans and lights turning on when you power the computer on?

Comment: @turbo-j - Seems like the PSU was the problem. I disconnected a few drives and now it starts again. Thanks! If you could write this as a reply I'll set it as the answer in case anyone else encounters a similar problem.